# Youtube: Customize Embed

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I want to add youtube video list but not video player. So what I need is

- Video Title
- Video Thumbnail
- Video Duration

Somehow I manage to get Image Thumbnail by using this `http://img.youtube.com/vi/4wew2uWoARw/hqdefault.jpg` but I couldn't found how to add title and duration.

Can anyone help me to get these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve JSON metadata about a video given its id using the Data API v2: `https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_ID?v=2&alt=jsonc`, e.g.

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/4wew2uWoARw?v=2&alt=jsonc